# In a Quiz, how can i instead of "Say A, B or C" let the user use one of the three response words?

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

**VIA Actions Console, not Dialogflow!**
After several days I finally finished to create a Quiz that works like this.
Google Mini says: "What is the capital of France? A) Rome, B) Berlin or C) Paris ?"

In my scene i have two conditions.

```
scene.slots.status == "FINAL" && intent.params.choosenABC.original == session.params.antwort

AND

!(scene.slots.status == "FINAL" && intent.params.choosenABC.original == session.params.antwort)
```

So here, these conditions check whether the user says the correct letter coming from the session parameter "antwort".
Everything works smooth as long as the user says "A", "B" or "C".

**But how can i compare a condition to what the user says?**
In the above example i want the user to be able to say "Rome" or "Berlin" or "Paris" and the condition to check these entries.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As i found some variables on a Dialogflow forum i tried out these, but none did work:
1.) $action.input.TEXT 2.) $action.input.raw 3.) $user.intent.TEXT 4.) $user.intent.raw

Comment: It would be awesome if just someone could even tell me that something like intent.params.original does exist or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of questions packed in there, so let's look at each.

**Does `input.params.original` exist?**

In short, yes. You can see the [documentation of the request Intent object](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/fulfill#Intent) and you'll see that there is `intent.params.*name*.original`. Your question seems to suggest this would work as well.

There is also `intent.params.*name*.resolved` which contains the value after you take type aliases into account.

**I found some variables on a Dialogflow forum...**

Those only work if you're using Dialogflow and don't make any sense when you're looking at Action Builder.

**How to match**

You don't show the possible value of `session.params.antwort` or how you're setting `antwort`. But it sounds like it makes sense that you're setting this in a handler. So one thing you could do is to set `antwort` to the city name (or whatever the full word answer is) and set `letter` to the letter with the valid reply. Then test both against `original` to see if there is a match.

But, to be honest, that starts getting somewhat messy.

You also don't indicate how the Intent is setup, or if you're using an Entity Type to capture the answer. One great way to handle this, however, is to create a Type that can represent the answers, and use a [runtime type override](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=builder#runtime_type_overrides) to set what the possible values and aliases for that value are. Then, you can control exactly what the valid value you will use to compare with will be.

For example, if you create a type named "Answer", then in your fulfillment when you ask the question you can set the possible values for this with something like

```
conv.session.typeOverrides = [{
    name: 'Answer',
    mode: 'TYPE_REPLACE',
    synonym: {
      entries: [
        {
          name: 'A',
          synonyms: ['A', 'Rome']
        },
        {
          name: 'B',
          synonyms: ['B', 'Berlin']
       },
       {
          name: 'C',
          synonyms: ['C', 'Paris']
       }
    ]
  }
}];
```

If you then have an Intent with a parameter of type `Answer` with the name `answer`, then you can test if `intent.parameter.answer.resolved` contains the expected letter.

**Adding a visual interface**

Using runtime type overrides are particularly useful if you also decide to add support for a [visual selection response](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-selection) such as a list. The visual response builds on the runtime type override to add visual aliases that users can select on appropriate devices. When you get the reply, however, it is treated as if they said the entry name.